# Winforms application using Devexpress not starting after registering

Tags: winforms, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui, xtraeditors

This is really weird issue; I tried everything I can but nothing resolved my problem. I was running trial version of the Devexpress XtraEditors suite and my Winforms app was running without any problems. Yesterday I registered my trial version of DevExpress and the application will run for a second, display the Devexpress logo for a minute and then shuts down automatically.

[image]

No error/exception is thrown but the application is closed right after that logo is shown.

Any idea how can I resolve this? I already contacted Devexpress but dropping a line here as well might help me too.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the lines(starting with DevExpress) from the lisences.licx file and see if you can run the project.

Answer (score 0):

This post fixed my problem, if anyone else is experiencing the problem, please refer to this post https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A705